# How do I set $PATH using PHP?

Tags: java, php, linux, path

My site is being hosted on a shared server so I don't have su access. I needed to run a piece of code with java but it's not available on the server. So I got a self-extracting version of java and put it on the server in my home directory. Then I gave executable permissions to java and I try running the code. I have to use relative paths when running the file because of the restrictions of the server.

Trying to run the java file `../java/bin/java -jar 'javafile.jar'` gives me the following:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libjli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I looked and `libjli.so` is located at `../java/lib/i386/jli/libjli.so`. So I'm thinking that because I'm running java using a relative path it doesn't exactly know how to look for the other files. I'm hoping that if I can add `absolute/path/to/java/bin` to `$PATH` then this issue will be resolved.

So once I'm running my PHP, I can use `dirname(__FILE__)` to get the full path of my java bin directory. I've tried the following code:

```
exec('export PATH='.$bin_path.':$PATH', $output, $return);
print_r(array(getenv('PATH'), $output, $return));

Prints:
Array(
  [0] => /usr/local/admin/bin:/usr/local/admin/bin/servers:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin,
  [1] => Array(),
  [2] => 0
)
```

So nothing was added to `$PATH`, no output was given, and the command returned a successful exit value. Is it just the restriction of the server that is preventing me from getting this working?

Comment: Try `dirname(realpath(__FILE__))`

Comment: @CianGallagher - `dirname(__FILE__)` is giving the same result as `dirname(realpath(__FILE__))` =(

Comment: It is likely likely to do then with the fact you probably doen't have access to `exec()` or `shell_exec()` for that matter. 99% of shared hosting providers will not give you access to either of those function for security reasons. If you want access I'd look into getting a VPS. The best service I use is Amazon AWS, they have a free tier that you can use here: http://aws.amazon.com/free/

Comment: Adding to that, I would never trust a shared hosting provider that would give you access to those functions either..

Comment: @CianGallagher - I agree. I'm planning on moving to Amazon once the site is in production. It's cheaper for me to develop here though. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, this is not going to work.

```
exec('export PATH='.$bin_path.':$PATH', $output, $return);
```

It will launch a child process with a shell, run the `export` command in the shell, and then the shell will exit.  But the `export` command only changes `$PATH` for that shell.

I'm not sure, but I suspect that you need to use `putenv`.

> I'm hoping that if I can add absolute/path/to/java/bin to $PATH then this issue will be resolved.

Well, it could only help if you used a simple command name for invoking the `java` command.

And it would be simpler to just run `java` using the full absolute pathname; e.g. `"/absolute/path/to/java/bin/java"`

Comment: I didn't realize that exec spawned a child process. $PATH was set fine there. I can just rework my code to run the java command during that same exec call. And as a side note, `putenv` also did not work.